# Pytest in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda, pytest

Is there any way we can perform unit testing on functions in an AWS lambda function using pytest?

Suppose I have a lambda function like the following:

```
def func1(x,y):
   return x+y

def func2(x,y):
   return x-y

def handler(event,context):
   x = event["x"]
   y = event["y"]
   
   def func3(x,y):
      return x*y

   print(func1(x,y))
   print(func2(x,y))
   print(func3(x,y))
```

Pardon extra simplicity of the functions. I would like to do unit testing using **pytest** on these functions `func1`, `func2` and `func3`.

Is there any way I can do it in AWS lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special in the code you have introduced.

It is true that `def handler(event,context):` is the entry point of the lambda but rest of the functions are just regular python functions that you can write UT and test them.

The UT will not run when the lambda is deployed on AWS. They can run on the developer machine or in CI/CD env.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know whether I could run these pytests in AWS lambda, rather than from the developer machine.

Comment: I have a pipeline in which the some functions are dynamically created on the go. I would like to do the unit testing on those functions as well on the go. If I could run pytest in lambda, I could put those lambdas in the same pipeline and work with it.

Comment: I think you can do it. 1) you need to package pytest with your lambda 2) you need to call pytest programmatically from the handler.

Comment: I am a beginner in this field. I am able to package pytest within my lambda. Can you please help me in calling pytest programmatically from the handler?

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code